# google-cloud TypeError: gcs.bucket is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement cloud function but getting error if i
require it like this

```
   var storage =require('@google-cloud/storage')();
```

like this when deploying

```
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
```

so i resolved to using it as above but tried uploading a picture i am getting error  "TypeError: gcs.bucket is not a function"

```
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
```

///

```
exports.onFileChange = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((event) => {
 const bucket = event.bucket;
 const contentType = event.contentType;
 const filePath = event.name;
 console.log('Changes made to bucket');
```

///

```
 if(path.basename(filePath).startsWith('renamed-')){
     console.log("File was previously renamed");
     return;
 }
 const gcs = storage({
    projectId: 'clfapi'
  });
```

///

```
 const destBucket = gcs.bucket(bucket);
 const tmFiilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(filePath));
 const metadata = {contentType: contentType};
```

///

```
 return destBucket.file(filePath).download({
     destination: tmFiilePath
 }).then(() => {
     return destBucket.upload(tmFiilePath, {
         destination: 'renamed-' + path.basename(filePath),
         metadata: metadata
     })
   });
});
```

Comment: What version of the @google-cloud/storage module are you using?

Comment: i am using ^2.2.0 didnt version it i just ran install without it so i guess latest.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The API changed in version 2.x of the Cloud Storage node SDK.  According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/#using-the-client-library), you import the SDK like this:

> ```
> // Imports the Google Cloud client library
> const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
> ```

Then you can create a new Storage object:

> ```
> // Creates a client
> const storage = new Storage();
> ```

Then you can reach into a bucket:

```
const bucket = storage.bucket()
```