# Google Cloud storage is not a function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to connect to the Google Cloud Bucket through

```
 const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
 const gcs = storage({    //TypeError: storage is not a function
  "keyFileName": 'path-to-keyfile.json',
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": <PROJECT_NAME>,

 //SOME CREDENTIALS
});

const bucket = gcs.bucket(<BUCKET_NAME>)
```

but I am getting an error that storage is not a function. Is there some issue that i am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google-cloud TypeError: gcs.bucket is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032928/google-cloud-typeerror-gcs-bucket-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using the Node.js Cloud Storage client libraries version 2.3.4
I was able to connect to a bucket with this code:

```
'use strict';

async function quickstart(
  projectId = 'PROJECT_ID', // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
  keyFilename = '/home/folder/key.json' //Full path of the JSON file
) {
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage({keyFilename,projectId});
  const bucket = storage.bucket('BUCKET_NAME')
```

This was based on the [Quickstart documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) and the [constructor options](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/src/storage.ts#L240)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended methods didn't work for me, while updating GCS from 1.x to 5.x on an older project. Node 14, CommonJs (not modules).

But this finally worked:

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const gcs = new Storage({gcsProjectId});
```