# how to properly init google cloud storage using cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I want to use google cloud storage using cloud function like this

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')

exports.compressImage = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {

    const fileBucket = object.bucket; 
    const filePath = object.name; 
    const contentType = object.contentType; 
    const metadata = {contentType: contentType}

    const destBucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket)
    const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(),path.basename(filePath))

    return destBucket.file(filePath).download({
        destination: tmpFilePath
    })

});
```

but it seems that there is no return value when I return a promise like this

[image: e]

and I have error in this line when execute the program:

```
const destBucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket)
```

from the console it is said:

> TypeError: gcs.bucket is not a function

and then if I try to use this code to init gcs

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')()
```

i have error when run `firebase deploy` :

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers. TypeError:
>   Storage is not a function

please help

Comment: That message has nothing to do with the way you require the @google/cloud-storage module.  It's an ESLint warning with the ID "consistent-return".  It's documented here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return

Comment: This might help:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032928/google-cloud-typeerror-gcs-bucket-is-not-a-function

Comment: @SagarPathak thank you, thats exactly the answer I need