# Download image from Google cloud and display on React website

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to learn React and Firebase right now. I would like to

1. Download an image from my Google cloud storage
2. Display that image on my web page

I am following this guide here to download files: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

However it seems out of date. I followed the advice on this other stack overflow thread to change the package import. [google-cloud TypeError: gcs.bucket is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032928/google-cloud-typeerror-gcs-bucket-is-not-a-function).

So right now I am able to download the file, however I do not know how to access it. From what I understand it would be in memory, but how would I display it? The docs to download a file are here https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download.

This is currently what I have

```js
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

function MyPage(props: any) {

    const storage = new Storage({
        projectId: 'myProjectId',
    });

    const myImage = await storage
        .bucket('myBucket')
        .file('myImage.jpg')
        .download();
    });

    return (
        <div id="MyPageContainer">
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You're following a guide for the Firebase web client library for Cloud Storage, but you're using the nodejs server library.  They're very different.

Comment: Would this be the correct library? https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#node.js-apps

Comment: No, you're not using Firebase at all here.  You're use google cloud libraries for cloud storage.  Notice `@google-cloud/storage`

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. However, I can't find what I would need to import then. The guide I'm following doesn't mention which imports to use.

Comment: Why do you want to download from Cloud Storage to your web server? You should provide a link in your HTML so that the end-user downloads directly from Cloud Storage. There are performance and cost factors to consider. If you are delivering secure files directly from your web server, look at Signed URLs. This example shows how to download files from Cloud Storage using Node.js https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-nodejs Once you download the file, you will then need to create an HTML tag + location so the browser downloads from your server.

Comment: Andrew, please, could you show us what you did at the end? I am trying to do something similar. 
@JohnHanley I thought about signed URL but I would really like to avoid showing the user I am using Google buckets

Comment: Unless your webserver handles downloads for the user (not recommended), you will find it very difficult to keep your usage of Cloud Storage a secret. Why are you concerned? 1) The Cloud Storage servers provide details in the HTTP response headers. 2) You must provide a URL to Cloud Storage. This is either using the Google URL or via a DNS server CNAME. Neither methods hides where the object is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the download of files from Cloud Storage to your web server you should provide a link in your HTML so that the users can download files directly from Cloud Storage, as mentioned by @JohnHanley in the comments.

This will take off your hands the processing of the file through your app's back-end to Cloud Storage itself, which is more efficient, but there are performance and cost factors for you to consider implementing it. If you are looking to deliver secure files directly from your web server, you can replace that for Signed URLs, you can check the documentation for it in [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).

If you still choose to go with the processing through your we server, you can take a look at this [example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples) and once you download the file, you will then need to create an HTML tag + location so the browser downloads from your server.