# Design question for storing image resources for NextJS web app?

Tags: web-applications, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on a web app in NextJS and I'm wondering about the best way to store my image resources.

I'm considering a Google Cloud Storage and using a public bucket to serve the images through a public URL.  So in the web app code, I'd reference an image using:

```js
... 
<Image src="https://storage.googleapis.com/public-storage-folder/my-image.webp" />
...
```

This works fine but I'm concerned about having a public open bucket on GCP.  From my research, this seems to be a common practice given the GCP experts (I'm not talking about signed URL's): [Download image from Google cloud and display on React website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579961/download-image-from-google-cloud-and-display-on-react-website).

Another approach would be to add the images to the build of the web app container so the images are hosted "locally" in respect to the web app.

What would be the best practice and am I leaving any other options out?

Comment: Store public resources such as images in Cloud Storage. More reliable and cheaper. If someone is going to abuse your resources, it will be cheaper from Cloud Storage than from compute resources which have higher egress costs.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use GCS to store images and serve them through a public URL.
2. You can also go for including all images in your web app build and serve them as it is, this will allow you to serve images locally with your app. Will be a Good option if you need to keep your images private.

Check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/discover-object-storage-console#share_the_object) and [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) may be helpful.